# Can I run two while loop separately in function? if not how do I verify the list in python?

Tags: python, list

Can I run two while loop separately in function? if not how do I verify the list in python?

```
def ADD_RESULT():

    while True:
        code = input("Enter the code")
        if code in COURSE_CODE :
            print("Details found")
            break
        else:
            print("course  didn't match")
            continue
    print("")

    while True:
        sid = input("Enter student id")
        if sid in STUDENT_ID:
            print(" found")
            continue
        else:
            print(" not found")
            break
```

How do I use the while loop to verify this above python list?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: In the second loop you inverted the `break` and `continue` statements. And btw a `continue` at the end of a loop is useless. Apart from that your code seems correct. What is the issue?

Comment: it's not reading the second loop, directly showing that id not found in the second loop. even i put the right value it's showing id not found.

Comment: @Dhiman Please upload a reproducible code, which includes the two lists you are referring to in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a loop after a loop inside a function, even better you can run a loop after a loop in python. I read your code, there is probably a logic error. The expression `continue` works after `sid` is found in STUDENT_ID. Therefore the loop runs again. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want, you should replace `continue` with `break` inside the second loop.

```py
while True:
    sid = input("Enter student id")
    if sid in STUDENT_ID:
        print(" found")
        break
    else:
        print(" not found")
```

Also you don't have to use `continue` at the end of the loop. Therefore `continue` statement in the first loop is unnecessary.

After above revisions, code seems like below:

```py
def ADD_RESULT():

    while True:
        code = input("Enter the code: ")
        if code in COURSE_CODE:
            print("Details found\n")
            break
        else:
            print("course  didn't match")

    while True:
        sid = input("Enter student id: ")
        if sid in STUDENT_ID:
            print(" found")
            break
        else:
            print(" not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your loop logic in the 2nd `while` loop is not the same as in the 1st. Try replacing the position of the break statement. Also, continue is not necessary here.

```
def ADD_RESULT():

    while True:
        code = input("Enter the code")
        if code in COURSE_CODE :
            print("Details found")
            break
        else:
            print("course  didn't match")
    print("")

    while True:
        sid = input("Enter student id")
        if sid in STUDENT_ID:
            print(" found")
            break
        else:
            print(" not found")
```